# Pyspark: How to iterate through data frame columns?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm new to pyspark. I usually work with pandas. I to iterate through row by row using a column in pyspark. My dataset looks like:-

```
+-------------------+--------------------+--------+-----+
|           DateTime|           user_name|keyboard|mouse|
+-------------------+--------------------+--------+-----+
|2019-10-21 08:35:01|prathameshsalap@g...|   333.0|658.0|
|2019-10-21 08:35:01|vaishusawant143@g...|   447.5|  0.0|
|2019-10-21 08:35:01|     you@example.com|     0.5|  1.0|
|2019-10-21 08:40:01|     you@example.com|     0.0|  0.0|
|2019-10-21 08:40:01|prathameshsalap@g...|   227.0|366.0|
|2019-10-21 08:40:02|vaishusawant143@g...|   472.0|  0.0|
|2019-10-21 08:45:01|     you@example.com|     0.0|  0.0|
|2019-10-21 08:45:01|prathameshsalap@g...|    35.0|458.0|
|2019-10-21 08:45:01|vaishusawant143@g...|  1659.5|  0.0|
|2019-10-21 08:50:01|     you@example.com|     0.0|  0.0|
+-------------------+--------------------+--------+-----+
```

In the pandas data frame it also has a given index but in spark not.
In pandas:-

```
## pandas
usr_log = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
unique_users = usr_log.user_name.unique()
usr_log.sort_values(by='DateTime', inplace=True)
users_new_data = dict()
users_new_data[user] = {'start_time': None}

for user in unique_users:
    count_idle = 0
    ## first part of the question
    for index in usr_log.index:
        if user == usr_log['user_name'][index]:
            if users_new_data[user]['start_time'] is None:
                users_new_data[user]['start_time'] = usr_log['DateTime'][index]

            ## Second part of the question

            if usr_log['keyboard'][index] == 0 and usr_log['mouse'][index] == 0:
                count_idle += 1
            else:
                count_idle = 0
            if count_idle >= 5:
                if count_idle == 5:
                    users_new_data[usr_log['user_name'][index]]['idle_time'] \
                        = users_new_data[usr_log['user_name'][index]].get('idle_time') \
                          + datetime.timedelta(0, 1500)
                else:
                    users_new_data[usr_log['user_name'][index]]['idle_time'] \
                        = users_new_data[usr_log['user_name'][index]].get('idle_time') \
                          + datetime.timedelta(0, 300)
```

Same thing how can do it in spark?

For each user data generated after 5 mins(Like if the user starts at 8:30:01 the next log generated at 8:35:01). In the second question in I want to find an idle hour for each user. The calculation of idle hours is if he does not move the mouse or use the keyboard the next 30 mins(1500) then I add in user idle hours.

After converting dictionary value into data frame my expected output like:-

```
+--------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
|           user_name|         start_time|          idle_time|
+--------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
|prathameshsalap@g...|2019-10-21 08:35:01|2019-10-21 05:05:00|
|vaishusawant143@g...|2019-10-21 08:35:01|2019-10-21 02:15:00|
|     you@example.com|2019-10-21 08:35:01|2019-10-21 01:30:00|
+--------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: Can you post your expected output?

Comment: Can you check it again? @AjayKharade

Comment: Confused here, I am unable related input and output data set?

Comment: What you do not understand pls clarify me? Here, after sorting by Datetime, I find each user starting time if the start time is None. I hope you got it. @AjayKharade

Comment: Now, I am able to relate input and output, thanks. I have posted solution for same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to find for each user the first timestamp that they have you can simplify it first in pandas, do this:

```
usr_log[['user_name','DateTime']].groupby(['user_name']).min()
```

And for spark will be very similar

```
urs_log = sparkSession.read.csv(...)
urs_log.groupBy("user_name").agg(min("DateTime"))
```

you only will have to rename `DateTime` column to the one you want, and try to not use [for loops in pandas](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-make-your-pandas-loop-71-803-times-faster-805030df4f06).

In spark, you have a distributed collection and it's impossible to do a for loop, you have to apply transformations to columns, never apply logic to a single row of data.

Comment: Thank you for helping me. I have one more question. can I post here? same related to this question.@Alfilercio

Comment: I have added one more question here pls check it again. @Alfilercio

Answer (score 1):

Here is solution on same,

```
dataFrame = (spark.read.format("csv").option("sep", ",").option("header", "true").load("data.csv"))

df.show()
+-------------------+--------------------+--------+-----+
|           DateTime|           user_name|keyboard|mouse|
+-------------------+--------------------+--------+-----+
|2019-10-21 08:35:01|prathameshsalap@g...|   333.0|658.0|
|2019-10-21 08:35:01|vaishusawant143@g...|   447.5|  0.0|
|2019-10-21 08:35:01|     you@example.com|     0.5|  1.0|
|2019-10-21 08:40:01|prathameshsalap@g...|   227.0|366.0|
|2019-10-21 08:40:02|vaishusawant143@g...|   472.0|  0.0|
|2019-10-21 08:45:01|     you@example.com|     0.0|  0.0|
|2019-10-21 08:45:01|prathameshsalap@g...|    35.0|458.0|
|2019-10-21 08:45:01|vaishusawant143@g...|  1659.5|  0.0|
|2019-10-21 08:50:01|     you@example.com|     0.0|  0.0|
+-------------------+--------------------+--------+-----+
df1 = df.groupBy("user_name").agg(min("DateTime"))
df1.show()
+--------------------+-------------------+
|           user_name|      min(DateTime)|
+--------------------+-------------------+
|prathameshsalap@g...|2019-10-21 08:35:01|
|vaishusawant143@g...|2019-10-21 08:35:01|
|     you@example.com|2019-10-21 08:35:01|
+--------------------+-------------------+
```

Other Part -

```
df1 = df.withColumn("count",when(((col("keyboard")==0.0) & (col("mouse")==0.0)), count_idle+1).otherwise(0))

df2 = df1.withColumn("Idle_Sec",when((col("count")==0), 300).otherwise(1500))

df2.show()
+-------------------+--------------------+--------+-----+-----+--------+
|           DateTime|           user_name|keyboard|mouse|count|Idle_Sec|
+-------------------+--------------------+--------+-----+-----+--------+
|2019-10-21 08:35:01|prathameshsalap@g...|   333.0|658.0|    0|     300|
|2019-10-21 08:35:01|vaishusawant143@g...|   447.5|  0.0|    0|     300|
|2019-10-21 08:35:01|     you@example.com|     0.5|  1.0|    0|     300|
|2019-10-21 08:40:01|     you@example.com|     0.0|  0.0|    1|    1500|
|2019-10-21 08:40:01|prathameshsalap@g...|   227.0|366.0|    0|     300|
|2019-10-21 08:40:02|vaishusawant143@g...|   472.0|  0.0|    0|     300|
|2019-10-21 08:45:01|     you@example.com|     0.0|  0.0|    1|    1500|
|2019-10-21 08:45:01|prathameshsalap@g...|    35.0|458.0|    0|     300|
|2019-10-21 08:45:01|vaishusawant143@g...|  1659.5|  0.0|    0|     300|
|2019-10-21 08:50:01|     you@example.com|     0.0|  0.0|    1|    1500|
+-------------------+--------------------+--------+-----+-----+--------+

df3 = df2.groupBy("user_name").agg(min("DateTime").alias("start_time"),sum("Idle_Sec").alias("Sum_Idle_Sec"))

+--------------------+-------------------+------------+
|           user_name|         start_time|Sum_Idle_Sec|
+--------------------+-------------------+------------+
|prathameshsalap@g...|2019-10-21 08:35:01|         900|
|vaishusawant143@g...|2019-10-21 08:35:01|         900|
|     you@example.com|2019-10-21 08:35:01|        4800|
+--------------------+-------------------+------------+

df3.withColumn("Idle_time",(F.unix_timestamp("start_time") + col("Sum_Idle_Sec")).cast('timestamp')).show()
+--------------------+-------------------+---------+----------------------+
|           user_name|         start_time|Sum_Idle_Sec|          Idle_time|
+--------------------+-------------------+---------+----------------------+
|prathameshsalap@g...|2019-10-21 08:35:01|         900|2019-10-21 08:50:01|
|vaishusawant143@g...|2019-10-21 08:35:01|         900|2019-10-21 08:50:01|
|     you@example.com|2019-10-21 08:35:01|        4800|2019-10-21 09:55:01|
+--------------------+-------------------+---------+----------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me @Ajay Kharede. I have one more question related to this topic.

Comment: You can ask next thing, but if context is different, its good to put next question on SO.

Comment: Please check it again. Thank you again.@Ajay Kharade

Comment: Not sure, I am not able to match your output and unable to find logic to match it, I edited answer, is it something you are looking?

Comment: Sorry, You did not get my point. here I want to calculate the idle hour for each user. if any user does not move the mouse or use keyboard continues 30 mins. then add 30 min in idle hours. like any user time 10:30:45 to 11:06:00 not move the mouse or use the keyboard then I want to add 35:15 (35min15sec) (2019-10-21 00:35:15). @Ajay Kharade

Answer (score 0):

You should do as the following example:

- df.withColumn("user_name", **do_something**)

"**do_something**" can be any function that you define.

Comment: I only want to use the spark data frame. so when I create a new do_something() function for iterating how to use a spark.